# How to return 14th day from month which was 2 months ago with determinated time in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, time

How can I take the 14th day from month which was 2 months ago with time `23:59:59` in Oracle SQL ?
I have query like below and I need answer something like below (similar style):

```
select to_char(to_date(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -2)), 'YY-MM-DD'), 'YY/MM/DD) from dual
```

Above query return: `21/12/31`, nevertheless I need query like above which will return value: `'21/12/14 23:59:59'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'MM'), -2)
         + INTERVAL '13 23:59:59' DAY TO SECOND  AS day
FROM   DUAL
```

Which outputs:

> | DAY |
> | --- |
> | 2021-12-14 23:59:59 |

If you want formatted with a specific format then use `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'MM'), -2)
           + INTERVAL '13 23:59:59' DAY TO SECOND,
         'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
       ) AS day
FROM   DUAL
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8a14845262ae331bd4c5a2386f8d21b3)*

Comment: Good but could you make format of output like: 21/12/14 23:59:59 ?

Comment: @dingaro Just wrap it in `TO_CHAR` with your desired format model if you want to output in a format.

Comment: _"could you make format of output like: 21/12/14 23:59:59 ?"_   Please!  No 2-digit years!  EVER!.  I spent too much of my life in 1998-1999 remediating for Y2k.  By now, no one in IT should ever even _think_ about 2-digit years.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, then

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.
    
SQL> select trunc(last_day(add_months(sysdate, -3)) + 15) - interval '1' second as result
  2  from dual;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
14.12.2021 23:59:59

SQL>
```

---

Or, if it has to be a *formatted* string (above value is DATE):

```
SQL> select to_char(trunc(last_day(add_months(sysdate, -3)) + 15) - interval '1' second, 'yy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') as result
  2  from dual;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
21/12/14 23:59:59

SQL>
```

Comment: Hmmm your solution: select trunc(last_day(add_months(sysdate, -3)) + 15) - interval '1' second as result from dual returns me 22/01/14 but I need something like 22/01/14 23:59:59 as a result :) Can I update your solution please ?

Comment: @dingaro - that is why Littlefoot set the session's `nls_date_format` - so the client displays the time part of the date value. You can use `to_char()` with the format you require instead.

Comment: Exactly; I edited the answer and just applied TO_CHAR with desired format mask to code I previously posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can truncate to the start of the current month instead of using `last_day`, and then add 14 days and subtract one second - here using [date arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705) with fractions of days, but you could also use intervals (as @MTO shows):

```
select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -2) + 14 - 1/86400 from dual
```

Which gives you a date value of 2021-12-14 23:59:59. You can then format that however you need.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cb494a45f790b3ce90ff791cbdf553f4)

Your current approach converts between dates and string, but relies on implicit conversion, which isn't a good idea. I've included that in the fiddle so you can see it breaking with a different session setting.